# What would be the best method to use LaTeX as a template?

Tags: meteor, latex

I have a need to have a PDF document that has a very specific format. I have data that is in a Meteor 1.0 application stored in MongoDB. How can I use a LaTeX template in place of an HTML template?

I have a number of Meteor packages where I have repackaged JS libraries and written complete packages. I know how to do that.

I don't wish to use HTML for the output because I need the output to be very exacting. I can achieve that with LaTeX. What I am unsure of is how to use LaTeX as the template and inject data into the document before processing and ultimately printing.

Comment: Meteor has [PDF packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=pdf) but no LaTeX one. Here's your chance to wrap an existing library. Here's how I [re-packaged jQuery-rateit](https://github.com/dandv/meteor-jquery-rateit).

Answer (score 0):

Meteor is at 1.0.

On this version things changed a lot. You have to choose the packages that you want to use.
According to the documentation:

`Since the parts of the stack integrate seamlessly, if you don't want to think about how it all works, you don't have to. You don't have to understand that the platform is made up of Blaze, Tracker, DDP, Livequery, and Isobuild, or how these pieces fit together. But if you want to dive in and learn how the parts work, you can do that too, because they are independent projects.`

So you can code a meteor application without using Blaze. Check the meteor website for more information on this: https://www.meteor.com/projects

If you want to use Blaze (normal choise), you can get to know it better at https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze

and you can adapt an existing LaTeX to HTML convert and create a template dynamically.